# ORA-22831: Offset or offset+amount does not land on character boundary

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am getting error during Oracle Apex 4.2 application export.

> ORA-22831: Offset or offset+amount does not land on character boundary

[image]

Comment: How does it solved at above?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the LENGTH or the DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR function in any of your plsql code? If so you could take a look into LENGTHB and SUBSTRB.

http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/string_func.html#slen

LENGTHC or SUBSTRC may help as well

Comment: I have changed dbml_lob_getlength to lengthc but same error. However page export is working fine.

Comment: I also have deleted two pages (form and report) where student picture is being show. But sill export is throwing error.

Comment: Could you give us more details about your code and errormessage/logs?

Comment: I have used form to save student pictures into database and write code that use dbml_lob_getlength. Now I have removed form from application and trying to export full application but that through above error. However page level export working fine.

Comment: in that case the problem isn't related to the form. do you have anything else in your apllication? Any special characters? could you give us a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Added picture, export was working fine before adding picture LOB code in registration form

Comment: could you give us the code for the picture LOB, you have used? then someone can test it and give you a hint what the problem is.

Comment: I have removed that form from application and then tried to export full application then it shows same error.