# Deleting a row in IR in Apex 4.2

Tags: oracle-apex

Back with a new issue. I want to delete a row from an IR by having a delete icon as a column in the report itself and when I click on that icon a DA will fire which will call a code to delete that record and also will call  API to delete the rows from fnd_attached_documents.

I did the following

1. Created an IR with the following query :

   ```
   SELECT nvl(to_char(task_id), '-') "Title",

      '-' "Type",

      nvl(description, '-') "Description",

      '-' "Category",

      --       nvl(last_updated_by,'') "Last Updated By",

      nvl((SELECT v('APP_USER') FROM sys.dual), '-') "Last Updated By",

      nvl(last_update_date, SYSDATE) "Last Updated",

      dbms_lob.getlength(file_content) download,

      attachment_id,

      document_id,

      media_id,

      '' "Delete"

   FROM my_attachments

   WHERE task_id = :p2_case_number;
   ```

Delete is not a column in the table and *P2_CASE_NUMBER* is an Item. Once the report was created I went to the report attributes --> Column Attributes and clicked on the Edit icon of delete and in the column link selected the icon and target as URL gave the following URL -

My DA is as follows

Name - DELETE_ATTACHMENT

Event- Custom

Selection type - DOM Object

DOM Object Title

True Action : PL/SQL code

```
DECLARE

  lv_case_number NUMBER;
  lv_attachment_id NUMBER;

BEGIN

   lv_case_number := :P2_CASE_NUMBER;
   APPS.DELETE_FILE_ATTACHMENT(lv_case_number,lv_attachment_id);

END;
```

Now I am facing the following issue and dont know what to do about them

1. I need to pass the attachment Id coming from the report as the second parameter to procedure I am calling, so how do I do that?
2. I need to refresh my report region only so that when delete happens I dont have to refresh the page myself?

I am using **ebs r12** and **apex 4.2**

Thanks

Comment: Have you added working delete column?

Comment: Let me know more about: APPS.DELETE_FILE_ATTACHMENT

Comment: Do you know about this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238696/ora-22831-offset-or-offsetamount-does-not-land-on-character-boundary

Comment: You can achieve this by using javascript function.make a function that will execute after clicking the delete button on the column.this function will get the id of the clicked button and manipulate it to get the id of the attachment column,.

Comment: Thanks brenners1302 for your reply.. could you please give me the steps on how to do it??

Comment: There are two ways to achieve this, the second is to extend your original example as per www.eberapp.com/pls/apex/f?p=BLOG:READ:0::::ARTICLE:2116700346816536

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the attachment id to link attributes and also a css class, that you can reference later in the DA:
data-id="#ATTACHMENT_ID#" class="delete-row"

You will need a hidden item to save the attachment id of the clicked row. In this example:PX_ATTACHMENT_ID

Then create a DA that is triggered when the link is clicked:
Event:click,Selection type:jquery selector,jquery Selector:.delete-row

Event scope of the DA should be dynamic, otherwise it won't work after the first refresh of the region.

Add a true action:
Action:set value,Set Type:Javascript Expression,Javascript Expression:this.triggeringElement.getAttribute('data-id'),Affected Items:PX_ATTACHMENT_ID

Add another true action:
PL/SQL Code to delete the attachment and make sure that you add PX_ATTACHMENT_ID to Page Items to Submit

Add another true action:
refresh report

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=111339:2